# JUPYTER_PATH in environment variables not working

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I am trying to update `JUPYTER_PATH` for Jupyter notebook. I set the environment variables following [the jupyter documentation](http://jupyter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/projects/jupyter-directories.html) but still `jupyter contrib nbextension install --user`, for example, installed under `C:\Users\username\AppData\nbextensions` instead of `C:\somedir\AppData\Roaming\jupyter\nbextensions`.

Added these to my environment variables.

```
JUPYTER_CONFIG_DIR=C:\somedir\.jupyter
JUPYTER_PATH=C:\somedir\AppData\Roaming\jupyter
JUPYTER_RUNTIME_DIR=C:\somedir\AppData\Roaming\jupyter
```

`jupyter --path` shows

```
PS C:\somedir\> jupyter --path
config:
    C:\somedir\.jupyter
    C:\anaconda\python27\win64\431\etc\jupyter
    C:\ProgramData\jupyter
data:
    C:\somedir\AppData\Roaming\jupyter
    C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\jupyter
    C:\anaconda\python27\win64\431\share\jupyter
    C:\ProgramData\jupyter
runtime:
    C:\somedir\AppData\Roaming\jupyter
```

`jupyter --data-dir` shows

```
jupyter --data-dir
C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\jupyter
```

I think `C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\jupyter` needs to be removed but nor sure how. Can you please help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To set the user data directory, you should instead use the `JUPYTER_DATA_DIR` environment variable, in your case set to `C:\somedir\AppData\Roaming\jupyter`. You can also unset `JUPYTER_PATH` (see below for details).

Although it's not terribly obvious from documentation, the nbextension install command takes no notice of the `JUPYTER_PATH` environment variable, since it doesn't use the `jupyter_core.paths.jupyter_path` function, but uses `jupyter_core.paths.jupyter_data_dir` to construct the user-data nbextensions directory directly.

The entry `C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\jupyter` from the data section of the output of `jupyter --paths` *is* the user data directory, since `JUPYTER_PATH` is used *in addition to* other entries, rather than replacing any. For your purposes, I suggest you unset `JUPYTER_PATH`, since you can get what you want without it.

Comment: Ah `JUPYTER_DATA_DIR` that was it! I could not find it anywhere on the documentation. Thank you very much